# how convert VML arcsize to rx ry of svg

Tags: svg, vml

I need to convert some VML  to the equivalent  of svg, and I need to understand how to calculate the Rx and Ry from arcsize.
As I understand arcsize of VML is the percentage of half size of smaller segment, but what represent the measure, the chord subtended to the arc?
In svg I know rx and ry are the radius, but from what starting point? and why 2 radius?

I need a conversion explanation with a math formula or an example script in any language.

Comment: Well an elliptical arc has two radii because an ellipse has two radii, the minor and major ones, an ellipse with identical radii is called a circle.

Comment: @RobertLongson, ok I understand in an svg the arc is an elliptical arc, but what is the center of the two radii in a rect?

Comment: @RobertLongson rects in svg can have rx and ry, to make a rounded rect.

Comment: well yes they can, is that relevant to your question? An ellipse has two focii rather than a centre.

Comment: @RobertLongson I need to make a conversion, so yes it is relevant to understand how to calculate the two focii  in a rectangle starting from width and height if I need to create an algorithm.
But if you have already a working formula for the conversion is better.

Comment: Sounds like you want this... https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/implnote.html#ArcConversionCenterToEndpoint